# Не загружаются файлы на сервер

Tags: php, веб-сервер

Хочу загрузить файл на сервер по средствам php скрипта. Имею такие файлы.
HTML

```
<form method="post" action="upload_avatar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="7000000" />
  <input type="file" name=" my_file ">
  <input type="submit" value="Загрузить файл">
</form>
```

php

```
$uploaddir = '/s92640jz.bget.ru/public_html/avatars/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))  
{
     echo "Загрузка файла на сервер не удалась";
     die(); //or throw exception...
} 

//Проверка что это картинка

if (!getimagesize($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"])) {
     echo "Это не картинка...";
     die(); //or throw exception...
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n";
} else {
    echo "Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n";
}

?>
```

Права на папку avatars/ выставлены 777 
Проблема в том что постоянно выбрасывает ошибку Загрузка файла на сервер не удалась

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: Подозреваю что $_FILES массив. $_FILES[0]["..."]

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте

```
<input type="file" name=" my_file ">
```

на

```
<input type="file" name="userfile">
```

так как в PHP вы обращаетесь к `$_FILES['userfile']...`

Comment: Загрузка файла на сервер не удалась

Comment: Значит добавьте перед `if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))` строку `var_dump($_FILES);` и покажите данные, которые выведет эта функция.

Comment: array(1) { ["userfile_"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(24) "Ð‘ÐµÐ·Ñ‹Ð¼ÑÐ½Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpiypBYt" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(275343) } } Çàãðóçêà ôàéëà íà ñåðâåð íå óäàëàñü

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, очень странно. Тогда в php коде меняйте подстроку `$_FILES['userfile']` на `$_FILES['userfile_']` раз данные у вас приходят в этот элемент массива.

Comment: всё равно не работает, пишет Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, вы везде изменение сделали с `$_FILES['userfile']`?

Comment: Да везде, вот только я заметил что тут кавычки одни if (!getimagesize($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"])), а тут другие if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) Это может повлиять?

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, кавычки влиять не должны в данном случае ни на что.